# Summing Moving Range and Criteria, Grouping by Day

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I'm trying to do is sum the last 30 days based on criteria and group by the day, one day of code looks like this:

```
select
sum(case when f.hire_date__c between '2017-08-01 00:00:00' and '2017-09-01 
00:00:00' 
and t.createddate  between '2017-08-01 00:00:00' and '2017-09-01 00:00:00'
and t.name = 'Request' then 1 else 0 end) as Requests
            from case_task_c as t
            join case_file_c as f
            on f.id = t.case_file__c
```

I could adjust dates accordingly for the 30 day look back based on today's date, etc. What I can't figure out is to have this query group by day for each day, i.e, yesterdays results, the day prior, etc for the adjusted date ranges.

So far I have this:

```
select 
date(cast(f.hire_date__c as date)),
row_number() over (order by f.hire_date__c desc) as rownumber,
rr.Cancels as Cancels,
qq.hires as hires,
sum(rr.Cancels) over (rows between 1 following and 30 following) as 
CumulCancel,
sum(qq.Hires) over (rows between 1 following and 30 following) as Hires
from case_file_c as f
    left join(
            select
            cast(f.hire_date__c as date) as date1,
            sum(case when 
            t.name = 'Cancellation Request' then 1 else 0 end) as Cancels
            from case_task_c as t
            join case_file_c as f
            on f.id = t.case_file__c
            group by date1)
            as rr
            on rr.date1 = cast(f.hire_date__c as date)
    left join(
            select
            cast(f.hire_date__c as date) as date2,
            sum(case when f.hire_date__c is not null then 1 else 0 end) as 
            hires
            from sf_case_file_c as f
            group by date2) as qq
            on qq.date2 = cast(f.hire_date__c as date)
where f.hire_date__c is not null 
and f.hire_date__c >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
and f.hire_date__c between date_add('day',-30,current_date) and current_date
group by f.hire_date__c, rr.Cancels, qq.hires
order by f.hire_date__c desc
```

Even using 'current_date - interval -30 day' is just looking up.. the current date.

Using Postgres 8.0.2

Comment: Can you use https://sqlfiddle.com to make an example schema and link it in your original question?

Comment: use `group by date(cast(f.hire_date__c as date)),rr.Cancels, qq.hires`

Answer (score 0):

Use group by like following. You are converting datetime to date in column selection but not in group by

```
GROUP BY date(cast(f.hire_date__c as date)),rr.Cancels, qq.hires
```